# Product:find()->asArray->all(); как реализовать?

Tags: php, yii2

Не могу понять вот это: **Product:find()->asArray->all();**
Я понимаю какой результат будет после этого выражения но, как реализованы вот эти стрелочки. Да я знаю когда мы создаем объект **$obj = new Test();** мы можем обратиться к свойству или методу вот так **$obj->method();** или  так **$obj->properte;**.
Можно ли сделать так $obj->method()->propery;
Помогите разобраться с этой реализацией.
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: да, можно Product:find()->asArray()->all();

Answer (score 2):

Рассматривайте выражение `Products::find()->asArray()->all();` как последовательное выполнение следующих операций:

```
$p = Products::find();
$p = $p->asArray();
$p = $p->all();
```

Поскольку нам неизвестно, что делает каждый из ваших методов, рассмотрим общую идею кода в примере: `Products::find()->asArray()->all();`.

Реализовать это можно двумя следующими классами:

```
class Products{
    private function __construct() {}

    public static function find() { return new Product(); }
}

class Product{
    private $data; //объект stdClass, хранящий данные
    private $asArray;
    public $somePublicField;

    public function __construct() {}

    public function asArray() {
        $this->asArray = true;
        return $this;
    }

    public function all() {
        return json_decode(json_encode($this->data), $this->asArray); //конвертация объекта в массив, если $asArray = true
    }
}
```

Чтобы реализовать `$obj->method()->propery` используя код выше можно сделать так:

```
$p = Product::find()->asArray()->somePublicField;
```